# "Writable"-partition on Ubuntu Snappy Core smaller than remainder of free space on disk

Tags: partitioning, ubuntu-core, beagleboard

I have a question regarding the partitioning going on on Ubuntu Snappy Core.
I have deployed snappy on my BeagleBoneBlack (BBB) as per the official website's [instructions](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/), (the specific instructions for the BeagleBone - fairly far down on the page).

When I've written the image to my SD-card the partitioning should look like [this](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/filesystem-layout/), which it does. ~2Gb for system-a and system-b with the remainder free space allocated to the writable partition. My partitions:

[image: disks]

However, once running snappy I very quickly ran out of space on the writable partition. When I run `df -h` on the BBB it returns

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         239M     0  239M   0% /dev
tmpfs                         50M  4.7M   45M  10% /run
/dev/disk/by-label/system-a  976M  454M  455M  50% /
/dev/mmcblk0p4               1.6G  1.5G     0 100% /writable
tmpfs                        246M  4.0K  246M   1% /etc/fstab
tmpfs                        246M   88K  246M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        246M     0  246M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                        246M     0  246M   0% /var/lib/sudo
tmpfs                        246M     0  246M   0% /mnt
tmpfs                        246M     0  246M   0% /tmp
/dev/mmcblk0p3               976M  455M  455M  50% /writable/cache/system
/dev/mmcblk0p1                63M   55M  8.8M  87% /boot/uboot
cgmfs                        100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                         50M     0   50M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Similarly, when I open the properties for the mounted partition 'writable' on my computer rather than the BBB, this is shown:

[image]

So what's going on here? Why can't I access the rest of my partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some further research, and found this [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253355/ubuntu-hdd-not-correct-size) which lead me to believe that 'Disks' might be showing me something different than what I was looking for (I was under the impression that there were no unallocated space within partitions, obviously I was wrong).

GParted on the other hand paints a different picture:

[image]

- Total size of partition: 12.74GiB
- Used space: 1.47GiB
- Unused space: 96.10MiB

The numbers don't add up, and in properties it becomes clear what's going on:

[image]

So I unmounted the partition, selected it, and under partition chose 'check' and applied.

Problem solved.